# Paypal credit card not showing in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

[image]

I am testing the payment for paypal(ios sdk. 2.11.5).
But as shown in the image, credit card information is not showing up.
I put in the credit card information in sandbox buyer account.
Why is the credit card information not showing up?
I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to how your account is setup. Please read the following checklist..

1. Your account must be either Premier or Business.  Personal type accounts do not have this option.
2. PayPal Account Optional (a setting in your account) is turned on - this enables non-PayPal members to pay by Credit Card.
3. The email address you use to log into your PayPal Account must be verified.
4. Credit Card linked and verified.
5. The IP address of your hosted site is not on a blocked list.